# Solving Quartic Equation (Year 12/High School Algebra) - Need Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quartics

Solve:

$3072x^4-2880x^3+840x^2-90x+3=0$ has roots $\alpha$, $r$$\alpha$, $r^2$$\alpha$ and $r^3$$\alpha$

(7 Mark Exam Question)

How would I go about solving this equation using Viete's Formula's. After finding $\sum$$\alpha$, $\sum$$\beta$, $\sum$$\gamma$ and $\sum$$\delta$, I'm not really sure what to do next.

Using Viete's formula's would be preferable as this is what will be on my exam for solving quartics, but if there is a better way of doing it in an exam that would be better.

Comment: **Hint:** Start by factoring out a $3$.

Comment: I've done that but it still leaves me at the same problem; what to do after I've equated ∑α, ∑β, ∑γ and ∑δ to their corresponding values and equations.

Answer (score 1):

For class problems, quartics always have rational roots.  After you factor out $3$ the leading term becomes $1024x^4,$ the constant $1$, so the possible roots are of the form $\pm \frac 1{2^n}$ with $0 \le n \le 10$.  Clearly then $r=\pm \frac 12, \pm \frac 14,$ or $\pm \frac 18$.  That is a number to try, but you can get there.  In fact, the roots are $\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18, \frac1{16}$

To use Vieta, because of the form of the roots you can choose whichever two relations you want.  I would use the constant term, which gives $r^6\alpha^4=\frac 1{1024}$ and the $x^3$ term which gives $\alpha \frac {1-r^4}{1-r}=\frac {2880}{3072}=\frac {15}{16}$.  Again the solution $r=\alpha=\frac 12$ jumps out because of the $1024=2^{10}$ but grinding through the algebra would be a mess.

Comment: I know this is old, but you appear to be active: How do you know the $1024x^4$ must be in the form $\pm \frac 1{2^n}$?

Comment: @George_E:  It is not $1024x^4$ that is of that form, it is the roots.  The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says that all rational roots of a polynomial  with integer coefficients are of the form a factor of the constant term divided by a factor of the highest coefficient.  In this case the constant term is $1$ (after dividing out the $3$) so the numerator is $\pm 1$.  The highest coefficient is $1024$ so the denominator is a factor of that, which is of the form $2^n$ as claimed.

Comment: Yep sorry, that's what I meant. I get it now, thanks!